# Cannot install a specific git branch on github with pip - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, github, pip

I'm trying to install a forked repo (https://github.com/theatlantic/django-ckeditor/) on Github with pip but without success.

When I use

```
pip install -e git+git://github.com/theatlantic/django-ckeditor.git#egg=django-ckeditor
```

It does install the repo's content, but an older version of it, without the new changes I'm interested in. So I tried to force pip to get the most updated branch, which is apparently atl/4.3.x but I get this weird error, like if the branch's name would be incorrect or something like that :

```
$ pip install -e git+git://github.com/theatlantic/django-ckeditor.git@"atl/4.3.x"#egg=django-ckeditor
Obtaining django-ckeditor from git+git://github.com/theatlantic/django-ckeditor.git@atl/4.3.x#egg=django-ckeditor
  Updating /home/mathx/.virtualenvs/goblets/src/django-ckeditor clone (to atl/4.3.x)
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Clone of 'git@github.com:theatlantic/ckeditor-dev.git' into submodule path 'ckeditor/static/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev' failed
```

Am I making a mistake somewhere ?

Thanks.

Comment: What's your operating system? I just ran your exact command on Ubuntu Linux and it worked fine, checking out branch `atl/4.3.x`.

Comment: Linux Mint 15. My pip version is 1.4.1

Comment: Have you tried again recently? GitHub suffered a [DDOS attack earlier today](https://status.github.com/messages) that might have affected you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user in IRC came in asking about this similar situation, and I think the answer we found applies here as well. (The user linked to this question saying "the same thing is happening", that's how I came across it.)

Consider the output from the OP:

> Obtaining django-ckeditor from git+git://github.com/theatlantic/django-ckeditor.git@atl/4.3.x#egg=django-ckeditor

The OP was attempting to pip install django-ckeditor via anonymous git (a `git://` URL).

The error was:

> Clone of 'git@github.com:theatlantic/ckeditor-dev.git' into submodule path 'ckeditor/static/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev' failed

If you look at https://github.com/theatlantic/django-ckeditor/blob/atl/4.3.x/.gitmodules, django-ckeditor pulls in ckeditor-dev, and does so with an SSH URL.

GitHub does not allow anonymous clones via SSH. Any use of git via SSH must use a registered SSH key. A user would have to sign up for GitHub, register their public key, and configure the private key appropriately to be used when this installation is happening.

The repository owner (`theatlantic`) should change their submodule URL to an `https://` URL, or anonymous `git://`.

Answer (score 6):

The error message you posted:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

...indicates you don't have access to the repo.

You might have luck using GitHub's HTTP URL instead:

```
pip install -e git+http://github.com/theatlantic/django-ckeditor.git#egg=django-ckeditor
```

Comment: How can I change the email that shows on the error message (,,,@github.com)

Comment: In what message?